# A problem concerning chain rule and partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let be $G : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^{\infty}$ function.
Suppose to indicate with $x,y,z$ the standard variables in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and another $C^{\infty}$ map $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given.
Suppose to have $G$ expressed like $G(x,y,f(x,y,z))$.
How can I compute
$\frac{\partial G(x,y,f(x,y,z))}{\partial{x}}$? Can someone give me a rigorous proof of the result or a reference where I can find it?

I have tried searching on the web (this site included), finding some formulas or advices, but unfortunately all of them are without a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
H(x, y, z) &= (x, y, f(x, y, z)) \\
&= (H_x(x, y, z), H_y(x, y, z), H_z(x, y, z)), \text{so} \\
H_x(x, y, z) &= x\\
H_y(x, y, z) &= y\\
H_z(x, y, z) &= f(x, y, z)
\end{align} 
Then the function you're interested in is
$$
U = G \circ H
$$
By the chain rule, 
$$
DU(x, y, z) = DG(H(x, y, z)) \cdot DH(x, y, z)
$$
where $DG$ and $DH$ indicate the matrices of partial derivatives of the two functions. 
In particular, looking at the first element of the left $1 \times 3$ matrix, $DU$, we get
(by the rules for multiplying matrices):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(x, y, z) &=  \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(H(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac{\partial H_x}{\partial x}(x, y, z) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(H(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac{\partial H_y}{\partial x}(x, y, z) + \frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(H(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial x}(x, y, z) \\
&= \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x, y, f(x, y)) \cdot 1 + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(x, y, f(x, y, z)) \cdot 0 +
 \frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(x, y, f(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y, z) \\
&= \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x, y, f(x, y)) +
 \frac{\partial G}{\partial z}(x, y, f(x, y, z)) \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y, z) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Dear John, your answer is great! Thank you :)